Select2 js with checkbox options
I want to have checkbox to select in my options but don't know what to do.
References
Here is my select box code:
<select class="form-control select2" id="data-set" name="data[]" multiple="multiple">
      @foreach($data as $row)
            <option value="{{ $row->name }}">{{ $row->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>

Js code:
$('#data-set').select2({
      placeholder: "Select options",
      allowClear: true
});


first of what is your question

Checkbox options with multiple selection in select2 js

See if you can adapt this answer to what you need.

Link is good but not covering my expectation with Multiple checkbox selection on options

See this adaptation helps you

settings underneath allowClear: true you must add multiple: true
